# Composer package not found in private repository

Tags: git, composer-php

I'm using Composer to load my private remote repository from BitBucket:

```
{
    "require": {
        "pico/pico-core": "dev-dev"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://git@bitbucket.org/picodevelopmentteam/php-server-core.git"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "PicoApi\\": ""
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

My pico-core composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "pico/pico-core",
    "require": {
        "facebook/php-sdk": "@stable",
        "everyman/neo4jphp": "dev-master",
        "predis/predis": "1.0.1",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "PicoCore\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                                                           
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package pico/pico-core could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

Where does the package name being set?

**Update:**
I get this error as well:

```
Reading composer.json of https://git@bitbucket.org/vendor/repository.git (FixingIssues)
```

I do have a FixingIssues branch but that's not the branch i was telling him to go to (I defined dev-dev as the right branch)

Comment: Do you have a branch called `dev` in your remote repo?

Comment: no its dev-dev.. I added the dev- prefix to it

Comment: If the name of the branch in your repo is `dev-dev` then in `composer.json` it should be `dev-dev-dev`. The first `dev-` tells composer you want the latest dev version from the branch it precedes.

Comment: so I have a branch named development. I wrote "pico/pico-core": "dev-development" but yet the error is the same

Comment: weird, when i tried with dev-dev-dev it worked... how come ?

Comment: Had you just renamed your branch to `development`? If `dev-dev-dev` works your branch must have been called `dev-dev`.

Comment: i have 2: development and dev-dev. when trying dev-development it didn't work. when tried dev-dev-dev it did work, how come ?

Comment: Is the same `composer.json` in both branches?

Comment: yes it is.. I think I'll remove dev-dev.. it was just for testing.

Comment: Try without the `dev-` prefix as you have already set the `minimum-stability` to `dev`.

Comment: sweet, I removed the dev-dev branch and now the dev-development works

Comment: Cool! Glad you got it working :-)

Comment: by the way, can I update the my repository from the vendor? I mean from the project that loaded it as a dependency ? Lets say I'm changing something in my vendor/pico/pico-core.. can I push it back to its repository ?

Comment: Afraid not. The vendor libs don't include the necessary .git directories.

Comment: I think I did see a .git there, but I can add it as a subtree

Comment: Don't add it as subtree! Add `vendor` into `.gitignore` instead. Composer will clone the repository if asked to (`--prefer-source`), or if no other way is possible (no distribution zip/tgz file available), and this clone, when ignored in `vendor`, will act as a standalone repository that can be worked on. Be careful though to not overwrite changes made when installing or updating the dependencies.

Comment: @Sven second time you save me today :) i saw it cloned it, but does it mean i can just get into inside the folder and push it? Eve do its inside a different git (although ignored)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your required version is almost certainly incorrect as you have a `minimum-stability` of `dev` (which is rarely a good idea).

```
...
"require": {
    "pico/pico-core": "dev-dev" //ensure the dev branch actually exists
},
...
```

Here's a useful guide to composer stability flags: https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html